# cannot include glade file in setup.py

Tags: python, package, glade, setup.py

I am trying to include a layout.glade file in setup.py.

```
package_data={'': ['src/layout.glade'],}, include_package_data=True



data_files=[('my_data', ['src/layout.glade'])],
```

but it still prints the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/a3k", line 9, in <module>
 load_entry_point('a3k==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'a3k')()
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/main.py", line 571, in main
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/main.py", line 40, in __init__
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'layout.glade': No such file or directory
```

my directory structure is :

```
├── DESCRIPTION.rst
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── a3k.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── build
│   └── bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64
├── dist
│   └── a3k-1.1.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bittorrenter.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── create.py
    ├── layout.glade
    ├── main.py
    ├── messages.py
    ├── pieces.py
    ├── scrape_test.py
    ├── test.py
    └── torrent.py
```

i have also modified the MANIFEST.IN file as follows:

```
include DESCRIPTION.rst
include src/layout.glade
recursive-include src *
```

i have read many other questions and have tried them all  but none of them help